# Memory leak in JBoss

Tags: java, soap, jboss

I am having a very strange behavior in JBoss, and I'd like avail myself of the Collective Wisdom of the SO Crowd.

We're using JBoss (4.0.4 I think) to serve SOAP calls. In fact, it's used as glorified RPC server, no more. We're running out of memory when we have 20+ clients sending their requests at the same time. The requests consist of the incoming rather small request (proper SOAP) and the returning result packet that is essentially one long SOAP string (and the contents of the string are XML). Yes I realize this is suboptimal. Don't ask.

I've traced the leak to an instance of org.jboss.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder that hold 4 million objects (strings and Integers). Now, even the longest response does not carry 4MB of data. The requests are all smaller than 40K. Something is fishy there, but I can't find any documentation on the Web.

Can someone tell me what the recorder is used for? And how do I get rid of it? Or may be configure it to be less memory-hungry? Any help is appreciated.

---

Update: To clarify - I did do memory dump, and the dump shows an array or 4,000,000+ objects, Strings and Integers. The array is owned by a org.jboss.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder which is in turn held by these guys:

org.jboss.axis.message.SOAPEnvelopeAxisImpl@0x19c31fd8 (141 bytes)  : field recorder
org.jboss.axis.message.RPCParamElementImpl@0x19c32260 (123 bytes) : field recorder
org.jboss.axis.message.SOAPBodyAxisImpl@0x19c32160 (121 bytes) : field recorder
org.jboss.axis.message.RPCElement@0x19c321e0 (124 bytes) : field recorder
org.jboss.axis.encoding.DeserializationContextImpl@0x19c332f0 (67 bytes) : field recorder
org.jboss.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder$objArrayVector@0x19c33398 (24 bytes) : field this$0

The data structures of our own app are quete bloated, but not to this degree.

Another update: powers that be have found a "powers-that-be-solution": we're switching to 64-bit memory. Hurray.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Don't assume there's a bug in JBoss; assume the bug is in your code.  You've already identified one 'sub optimal' condition of your software.  Why can't there be more?

Comment: My question is: what are you doing running such an old version of JBoss?  It's 2.5 years old.  You'll often find people a hesitance or even reluctance from people to help with outdated software.

Comment: @Gortok - I did assume our own fault, but that damned array is responsible for half the meory in use, and it has noting to do with us. And, the way it's held (see update), it may be allocated for each request in progress-that explains why we fail only when certain number of requests are in progress.

Comment: @cletus: - "Enterprise" environment - three dev teams on 3 continent and no one ready to take responsibility.

Comment: Ive just been running a case with bea support on some thing of the same sort. The info needed for them to do anything was: JRA recordings, MissionControl MemLeak screenshots, garbage collection logs and any dump files from the jvm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run with the JVM arg -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.  This will give you heap dumps when you run out of memory.  You can then analyze the heap dump with the *jhat* tool (it comes with your JDK).  Alternatively, you can use the *jconsole* tool (which also comes with your JDK) to request a heap dump at any time using the memory management MBeans.

It will tell you what those 4 million objects actually contain which might give you insight into why the software isn't releasing that memory.

EDIT:

It seems you're not the only one with this issue.  There are 2 bug reports filed with Axis

[AXIS-2698](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2698)

[AXIS-2749](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2749)

See also [AXIS-1771](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-1771), it has some interesting information regarding deserialization and ways to mediate its impact.  Which version of Axis are you using?

Comment: How do you think I've established that SAX2EventRecorder is the culprit? Damn, people around here are getting used to newbie questions and don't expect any better.

Comment: Voting back up: Arkadiy, it may have been unhelpful for you, but the way you phrased the question made it come across as 'newbie', especially since the title is 'Memory Leak in JBoss'.  The first rule of using a commercial tool is to assume the bug is in your code; not the commercial tool.

Comment: I can only work with the information you give me.  Perhaps you should be more specific next time.  Anyway, what is the content of the objects in the SAX2EventRecorder?

Comment: Yeah, gotta admit: even though the answer may have covered what you've done, downvoting it and then lambasting the poster leaves me thinking "you're on your own buddy".

Comment: @kevin: to quote the question: SAX2EventRecorder that hold 4 million objects (strings and Integers). That's what the contents is.

Comment: @Arkadiy, what are those Strings?  Are they snippets of your (de)serialized xml or are they something completely different?  Are they mostly the same bits and pieces or random?

Comment: Way to jump on the people trying to help you, dude. Your initial question should have stated the exact troubleshooting steps you took - if you ran jconsole, HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, etc. People posting answers shouldn't assume you took any steps you didn't mention.

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, the strings are snippets of HTML. Thanks for pointing out the bugs - I saw the first two, but not the last one. It would be nice to know what "settings and things" in the last comment. It certainly helps to know about 1.4. We do have 1.4 in our codebase - do we use it? Will find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, run the application under Java 6. The latest version includes [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) for profiling. It should be able to show the growth of memory. You can attach to a Java 5 VM, but it doesn't show as much.